# Characterization of weak convergence with lower semicontinuity

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\mu_n, \mu$ be probability measures on a Polish space $X$. We say that $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if
$$
\int f d\mu_n \to \int f d\mu \:\:\;\;\;\; \forall f \in C_b(X)
$$
Show that it is equivalent to ask

$$
\int g d\mu \leq \liminf \int g d\mu_n \:\:\;\;\;\; \mbox{for all g lower semicontinuous bounded from below}
$$

This should be standard but unfortunately I could not find any reference

Comment: The space doesn't need to be complete or separable. There are several ways: 1. you may consider to approximate the lower semicontinuous by a sequence of continuous and bounded function. 2. Considering a lower semi continuous function $f \geq 0$ (we can always substract $\inf f$,) so using Portmanteau theorem $\forall x>0, \mu(f>x) \leq \liminf_n \mu_n(f>x),$ integrating over $x>0,$ and using Fatou's lemma: $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\mu(f>x)dx \leq \int_0^{+\infty}\liminf_n \mu_n(f>x)dx \leq \liminf_n \int_0^{+\infty}\mu_n(f>x)dx,$ so $\int fd\mu \leq \liminf_n \int f d\mu_n$

Comment: The equivalence remains true for lower and $\mu$-a.e semi continuous functions. By Considering $-f$ you have a result with upper semi continuous functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know a reference, but you can argue as follows: by the Skorokhod representation theorem we may find random variables $X_n,X$ (changing the probability space if necessary) such that the law of $X_n$ is $\mu_n$, the law of $X$ is $\mu$ and such that $X_n \to X$ almost surely as $n \to \infty$. Letting $g$ be lower semicontinuous and bounded from below, we want to show that
$$\mathbb{E}(g(X)) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}(g(X_n)).$$ By lower semicontinuity, as $X_n \to X$ we almost surely have $g(X) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}g(X_n)$ and therefore Fatou's lemma shows $$\mathbb{E}(g(X)) \leq \mathbb{E}(\liminf_{N\to\infty}g(X_n)) \leq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{E}(g(X_n)).$$